# Compact a MySQLI fetch_assoc() to one array per column

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

thanking to [Detect data type while using fetch_array with MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475072/detect-data-type-while-using-fetch-array-with-mysqli/16475487?noredirect=1#16475487) and [Output a property with PHP5 and method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554973/output-a-property-with-php5-and-method-chaining), I am able to populate a json object in a MySQL query using MySQLi and method chaining.

```
  /// Populate an array with the results;
  public function populate(){
    ($rows=array());

    while($row=$this->result->fetch_assoc())
      $rows[]=$row;

    $this->rows=$rows;

    $this->last=$this->rows;
    return $this;
  }
```

I obtain

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "datein": "2012-06-06 09:59:05"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "datein": "2012-06-06 11:32:45"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "datein": "2012-06-07 00:47:19"
  }
]
```

How can I obtain instead

```
{
  "id": [1,2,3]
  "datein": ["2012-06-06 09:59:05","2012-06-06 11:32:45","2012-06-07 00:47:19"]
}
```

in order to have an alternative and compact version of the results?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to your help, I prepared this sort of mysql wrapper and both the fetching methods are provided: 
http://ross.iasfbo.inaf.it/~gloria/decibel-class

Comment: You'll find that your first version is much better and easier to work with. I advise against your idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact I will have the two methods and I could use the one or the other depending from the situation.

Comment: Anyway, downvoting me for having asked an alternative way to fetch data is kinda odd :|

Comment: I suppose that the downvotes are because you didn't strictly tried to achieve the result you wanted, but this question looks like a properly disguised "give me the code" one. IMHO, i didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your array with 2 arrays within it, one to hold `id` the other to hold `datein`

```
public function populate(){
    $rows = array('id'=>array(), 'datein'=>array());

    while($row=$this->result->fetch_assoc())
      $rows['id'][] = $row['id'];
      $rows['datein'][] = $row['datein'];

    $this->rows = $rows;

    $this->last = $this->rows;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your code to:

```
/// Populate an array with the results;
public function populate() {
    $rows = array();

    $this->result = array();
    while ($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc())
        foreach ($row as $field => $value)
            $this->result[$field][] = $value;

    return $this;
}
```